# Android L Developer Preview flashing stuck on cache erasing

Tags: android, adb, android-5.0-lollipop

I tried to flash the Android L Developer Preview(http://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html) onto my Nexus 5 (no custom ROM or bootloader) following the steps at https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images. When using flash-all.bat, I **ALWAYS** get stuck on

```
erasing 'cache'...
```

The only thing I can do is reboot the phone by holding down the power button until it is off. Then when I boot again I see the Google logo followed by the green Droid which probably means recovery mode. Sometimes under the Droid there is a blue progress bar, just like the one that comes up when updating, but it does not show a progress but rather just indicates action. When the Droid is up I also cannot reach the phone with fastboot or adb.

I also tried reverting back to Andrid 4.4.4, but I get the same error. Nobody else seems to have this problem, they all erase their cache in a matter of seconds and then format it.

It would be really cool if anybody could help me with either reverting to Android 4.4.4 or successfully flashing Android L.

Benedikt

Comment: Update: When using `fastboot -w` to erase userdata and cache, it also gets stuck on `erasing 'cache'...`. The phone just says `erasing...` and I cannot access it with fastboot anymore until I reboot.

Comment: Try flashing from `Linux` machine. I had faced the same many times.

Comment: How long did you wait?

Comment: @VenomVendor I tried installing it via a virtual machine running Ubuntu, and it failed at the same part.

Comment: @HansKratz The first time I waited like 30 minutes, and the last time I did it I left my phone in this state for more than five hours. Most times I abort earlier.

Comment: Update 2: When I try to update without wiping userdata and cache (without -w), it gets stuck on erasing the system which I manually erased beforehand(in about 16 seconds) and which worked just fine when also wiping userdata and cache. Conclusion: It always gets stuck on the last erasing operation.

Comment: You can find someone using Linux, of try with Linux Live, You can run OS from the CD/PenDrive, but I strongly suggest you to use Linux.
`How Long did I wait(Windows)` more than 6-7 hrs and the result was nothing. `In Linux`, 5Mins max.

Comment: same problem w/ CyanogenMod for another device ....

Comment: So I also tried using a full Ubuntu machine, in this case a live DVD with Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit because it was already laying around here. And still the same error occurs. I am starting to think that this is an error with my phone. I also cannot open the recovery menu, I only have the Droid with this blue wireframe circle spinning. When I press the volume up key the screen becomes black and in the lower left corner the text "formatting /data" appears, but it also stays there forever without doing anything. I will contact the Google support as I do not know any other solution to this...

Answer (score 0):

Is your phone with unlocked bootloader? If no, type in console:

```
fastboot oem unlock
```

After that you should to  enter in bootloader, open shell and write:

```
fastboot erase boot
fastboot erase cache
fastboot erase recovery
fastboot erase system
fastboot erase userdata
```

Start "flash-all" script again and enjoy your Nexus.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work. As I said, it always gets stuck on some erasing operation. This time, using your method, it got stuck on erasing the boot partition. After I have reset the device I continued, but when using flash-all it again gets stuck on erasing the cache. I also tried formatting cache and userdata beforehand, then I manually ran the instructions in the flash-all.bat but I left out the -w parameter when using the update command so that it could not get stuck on the erasing process, but even though it did went through it only boots to the green Droid with the blue bar underneath.

Comment: @Benedikt, you didn't answer, is your bootloader unlocked? If yes, then try to erase all again and then just try unzip an archive with such disk images: system.img, userdata.img, recovery.img and boot.img . Unzip it into folder with adb. Reboot your phone into bootloader. Open shell and type "fastboot flash system system.img", "fastboot flash userdata userdata.img", "fastboot flash recovery recovery.img" and "fastboot flash boot boot.img". It should work.

Comment: Yes, my bootloader is unlocked. As I said, I already tried erasing it manually like you said. I also have the zip file unzipped, it contains the boot, cache, recovery, system  and userdata images and the android-info.txt. Using adb is in vain, it won't find the device as it cannot boot into Android, I can only connect with fastboot. I tried flashing the zip file with the image manually, using fastboot flash boot boot.img for each file respectively, but it still does not boot, even though this way I can flash the image completely without fastboot getting stuck on erasing something.

Comment: @Benedikt oh... Can you enter recovery mode?

Comment: I can get into the fastboot mode where you have some text in the lower left corner(something like "bootloader unlocked", the device id and some other info), and the green arrow pointing towards the power button where you can choose between "Start", "Restart bootloader", "Recovery mode" and "Power off", but when I try to enter the recovery mode it just shows the green Droid with the blue bar you also see when it is installing an update.

Comment: @Benedikt OK, try to load this [recovery](https://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager) for your Nexus 5 and try to write it via fastboot as recovery `fastboot flash recovery recovery-clockwork-6.0.4.5-hammerhead.img`.

Comment: Okay, flashing the recovery worked, I can now open the recovery. I tried to wipe cache and data. When wiping data, it says: `Formatting /data... Error mounting /data... Skipping format...`. The same goes for `/sdcard/.android_secure`.